# Strange behavior that happens when you cross the month with a date type in ts and js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, date

The following code works correctly with 5 displayed.

```js
const startDate = new Date(2022, 8, 26);
const endDate = new Date(2022, 8, 31);

const msInDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const diff = Math.round(Math.abs(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / msInDay);
console.log(diff);
```

However, when I set the endDate to 9/1, it shows 5 and does not work correctly. I have a feeling that this is the case when the month is crossed. What is happening?

Here is the code that does not work well The only thing that has changed from the above is the date.

```js
const startDate = new Date(2022, 8, 26);
const endDate = new Date(2022, 9, 1);

const msInDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const diff = Math.round(Math.abs(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / msInDay);
console.log(diff);
```

Comment: 31st of September is the same as 1st of october - because, there is no 31st of september - `console.log(new Date(2022, 8, 31))` to see what I mean - [important documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#monthindex)

Comment: @JaromandaX 
I see! The month is 0-11, so that makes it September. My bad. Thanks! You were very helpful!